# How to check the date cross the sunday and rest data

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

How to check the date cross the Sunday and reset the data?

I need to do reset on every Sunday, if I missed that on Sunday then the reset need to happen if user open the app the following increment date(i.e mon,tue, till saturday).

For Every Sunday or crossed the Sunday one time the reset need to happened, if user forgot to open the application on Rest date.

Following the my code which i try to implemented.
Which was not working as per my requirement,  Your feedback is highly appreciated.

```
        -(void) weekDaySundayToRefresh
        {
            NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
            NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
            NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth | NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:now];

            NSUInteger weekdayToday = [components weekday];
            NSInteger daysToMonday = (8 - weekdayToday) % 7;

            nextSunday= [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToSunday];

            NSLog(@"nextMonday : %@", nextSunday);
        }

        -(void) compareDate
        {
            NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; // it will give you current date
            //    NSDate *newDate = [MH_USERDEFAULTS objectForKey:@"USER_BACKGROUND_DATE"]; // your date

            NSComparisonResult result;
            //has three possible values: NSOrderedSame,NSOrderedDescending, NSOrderedAscending

            result = [today compare:refreshGoalsDate]; // comparing two dates

            if(result==NSOrderedAscending)
            {
                NSLog(@"today is less");
            }
            else if(result==NSOrderedDescending)
            {
                NSLog(@"newDate is less");

                NSDate *fromDate;
                NSDate *toDate;

                NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

                [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay startDate:&fromDate
                             interval:NULL forDate:refreshGoalsDate];
                [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay startDate:&toDate
                             interval:NULL forDate:today];

                NSDateComponents *difference = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                           fromDate:fromDate toDate:toDate options:0];

                noOfDaysCount = [difference day];
                NSLog(@"date difference:%ld",(long)[difference day]);
            }
            else
                NSLog(@"Both dates are same");
        }

    -(void) checkRefreshGoals:(int)sectionIndex rowIndex:(int)rowIndex
    {
        NSDateFormatter * formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSString * currentDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSString * initialNotificationDate = [formatter stringFromDate:refreshDate];
        NSDate *currentDate = [formatter dateFromString:currentDateString];
        NSDate *refreshDate = [formatter dateFromString:initialNotificationDate];

        if ([refreshDate compare:currentDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
        {
            NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");
            isGoalsRefreshed = NO;
        }
        else if ([refreshDate compare:currentDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
        {
            NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");
            if (sameDay == YES)
            {
                isGoalsRefreshed = YES;
                [self refreshDataOnSunday:sectionIndex rowIndex:rowIndex];
            }
            else if (noOfDaysCount > 7)
            {
                isGoalsRefreshed = YES;
                [self refreshDataOnSunday:sectionIndex rowIndex:rowIndex];
            }
            else
            {
                isGoalsRefreshed = NO;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"dates are the same");
            isRefreshed = NO;
        }
    }

-(void) refreshDataOnSunday:(int)sectionIndex rowIndex:(int)rowIndex
{
    if (noOfDaysCount > 7)
    {
        if (isGoalsRefreshed == YES)
        {

            // Do rest your data


        }
    }
    else if (sameDay == YES)
    {
        if (isGoalsRefreshed == YES)
        {
        // Do reset your data

        }
    }
    else
    {
        isGoalsRefreshed = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: will you store your last updated time?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to save todays date and DayNumber when user opens your app at first time and then you need to compare next app open date so you can estimate either Sunday is gone or not.

```
/*first check in userDefault for stored Date and Day
Store values in local and check with current date */

NSMutableDictionary *dictStoredData = [USERDEFAULT valueForKey:@"dateTimeDate"];

if (!dictStoredData) {
   // user comes first time so store it here
    dictStoredData =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSDate *today =[NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian =[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *comps =[gregorian components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSInteger weekday = [comps weekday];
    int nextSundayVal = 7 - (int)weekday;

    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *startDate = [format stringFromDate: today];
    [dictStoredData setObject:startDate forKey:@"startDate"];
    [dictStoredData setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",nextSundayVal] forKey:@"nextSundayVal"];

    [USERDEFAULT setObject:dictStoredData forKey:@"dateTimeDate"];
}
else{
        NSString *strEndDate = @"2017-01-08";
        NSString *strStartDate = [dictStoredData valueForKey:@"startDate"];
        int nextSundayVal = (int)[dictStoredData valueForKey:@"nextSundayVal"];
        NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate *startDate = [format dateFromString:strStartDate];
        NSDate *endDate = [format dateFromString:strEndDate];

        NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
        NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                            fromDate:startDate
                                                              toDate:endDate
                                                             options:0];

        int newDayCount = (int)[components day];

        if (newDayCount > nextSundayVal) {
            NSLog(@"sunday is gone so reload data!!");
            //save this date as a new date and check with this when user come again
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"sunday is not come yet!!");
        }

}
```

here strEndDate is next date when user opens your application so you can get it from `[NSDate date]` with same dateformater.
I have run this code in my machine and its printing **sunday is gone so reload data** so hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As like you we had flow, every friday and more than seven days, its need to update the server.
We did it with following code:
You need to update last updated date.
Check this out:

```
        if ([isFirday isEqualToString:@"Friday"]) {//This is my value from server side (they will give as friay), i think you dont need this condition.
            BOOL isSameDay;
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy,HH:mm"];
            NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:mennuRefreshTime];//Is an last updated date.
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
            NSString *temp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
            NSDate *lastDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:temp];

            NSString *currentDaystr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
            // Write the date back out using the same format
            NSDate *currentDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentDaystr];

            if ([lastDate compare:currentDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
                NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");
                isSameDay = NO;
            } else if ([lastDate compare:currentDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
                NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");
                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
                NSString *dayName = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
                NSString *lastupdateName = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:lastDate];

                if ([dayName isEqualToString:lastupdateName]) {
                    isSameDay = YES;
                }else{
                    isSameDay = NO;
                }

            } else {
                NSLog(@"dates are the same");
                isSameDay = YES;
            }
            if (isSameDay == YES) {
                return;
            }


            NSCalendar *calender =[[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
            NSDateComponents *components = [calender components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:lastDate toDate:currentDate options:0];

            int day = (int)[components day];
            if (day >= 7) {
                [self getTopList];
            }else{
                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
                NSString *dayName = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
                if ([dayName isEqualToString:isFirday]) {
                    [self getTopList];
                }else{
                    return;
                }
            }


        }
```